# How to change height of <FlatList/> in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to change width and height of `<FlatList />`.

I set the `height` style to the current `<FlatList />` but it never worked.

I can change the height of `<FlatList />` in no way.

This is my `render()` function and styles.

```js
render() {
    const listData = [];
    listData.push({ key: 0 });
    listData.push({ key: 1 });
    listData.push({ key: 2 });
    listData.push({ key: 3 });
    listData.push({ key: 4 });
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={listData}
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                    return (
                        <View
                            style={{
                                width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: 'green'
                            }}
                        />
                    )
                }}
                horizontal
                style={styles.flatList}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    flatList: {
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
});
```

And this is result of this code.

[image: Current result]

I found the answers for several hours but nothing helped me.

I am not sure why height style is not working.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

adding `flexGrow: 0` to the flatList style worked for me, so it will be:

```js
flatList: {
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  flexGrow: 0
}
```

Comment: this is a better solution than boxing the whole flatlist with a view component.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution. It works perfect for me!

Comment: except when you rotate the device?

Answer (score 84):

Set the height of `<View/>` and place `<FlatList/>` inside that `<View/>`

Comment: It do not allows to scroll

Answer (score 9):

Add `flexGrow: 0`. Don't mention height, the design might break when it comes to responsive

Example :

```js
<FlatList
  style={{
    flexGrow: 0,
  }}
  data={data}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{item.text}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

FlatList has prop contentContainerStyle. You can use it to style wrapper around FlatList. FlatList inherit this prop from ScrollView [read hear](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle)

Answer (score 2):

you can add `flexGrow: 0` to the flatList style worked for me, so it will be:

```
  <FlatList
   {...{otherProps}}
    style={{
      height: 50,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      flexGrow: 0
    }}
    />
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

give width then height working according to data

```
 <View style={{maxHeight:"50%",width:"60%"}}>
       <FlatList
            data={this.props.data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={styles.flatList}>
   <FlatList
      keyExtractor = { this.keyExtractor }
      data = { this.getPOs() }
      ListEmptyComponent = { this.renderEmpty }
      ItemSeparatorComponent = { Separator }
      renderItem = { this.renderItem }
   />
</View>
```

for me works add flex: 1 to the view

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    flatList: {
        flex: 1,
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
render() {
  const listData = [];
  listData.push({ key: 0 });
  listData.push({ key: 1 });
  listData.push({ key: 2 });
  listData.push({ key: 3 });
  listData.push({ key: 4 });
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList
              data={listData}
              renderItem={({item}) => {
                  return (
                      <View
                          style={{
                              width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: 'green'
                          }}
                      />
                  )
              }}
              horizontal
              style={styles.flatList}
          />
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      height:100
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  flatList: {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
});
```

Comment: Adding an explanation to your answer would make it much more useful to others.